# Python need to know complete data instead of object at 0x0000000003B2E048

Tags: python, class, pointers

Very simple code ;Tired of getting negative numbers ; dont do this

```
security = YahooSecurity(symbol, force_download, force_cache,
                                 interval, period, debug)
print(security)
```

The YahooSecurity is a class here when i print this it only prints the address below 
instrument.YahooSecurity object at 0x0000000003B2E048

Question :
if i want to print the complete data of it what shall be the python code to be used instead of print(security) here.

Comment: `print(vars(security))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, print all its properties to see what's available:

```
print(dir(security))
```

Then think about which properties you want to print, and print them.  For example if `dir()` tells you it has `price, exchange, symbol`, you can:

```
print(security.price, security.symbol, security.exchange)
```